# In Markdown, how do you put a table inside an ordered list?

Tags: markdown

Should it be possible to put a table inside an ordered list in markdown? If not, whats a recommended alternative way to do it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another way to do this is by adding two or more spaces (according to the level of nesting) at the beginning of the rows. Therefore this:

```
1. Some item
2. Item with table

  | xx|yyy|
  |---|---|
  |aa|bb|
  * Nested item with table

     | xx|yyy|
     |---|---|
     |aa|bb|
3. Another item.
```

**It should look like this:**
[image]

Comment: This is great - though I needed 3 spaces for this to work correctly. 2 spaces had no effect.

Comment: For me it must be 4 spaces

Answer (score 3):

I can't find a way to get it only with markdown.
but you can use [Inline HTML](https://superuser.com/editing-help#html) to replace ordered list, like

```
<ol>
<li> 1st

|xx|yyy|
|-|-|
|aa|bb|


<li>.
.
.
.
```

you can refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19950648/how-to-write-lists-inside-a-markdown-table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19976953/6493535)

Comment: The link refers to a different problem, putting a list in a table rather than putting a table in a list.